# Rails remote forms validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

Just a simple question, I have followed the [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised)

It's nice how for remote true works, but how can I validate the model ?

I have this one

```
<%= form_for [:admin,@course], remote: true  do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title, "The title:" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description, "Descripcion:" %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
 </div>
 <div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit "Send"%>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

How I handle the error?

```
def create

  @course = Course.new(params[:course])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @course.save
      format.html { redirect_to admin_index_url, :notice=> 'Done !!' }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { flash.now[:alert] = "Not done" 
                    render "new"
                  }
      format.js
    end
  end        
end
```

Any ideas why this does not work?

Comment: The line `if @course.save` will cause validations to run. What isn't working?

Answer (score 6):

Since your format.js blocks are empty,  and the create action is called via :remote=>true,  rails will do the default,  which is to look for create.js.erb to render back,  which it probably isn't finding.

To illustrate,  put this in the views directory in app/views/?/create.js.erb:

```
alert('HI');
```

Then put this in your controller to see an alternative:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @course.save
    format.html { redirect_to admin_index_url, :notice=> 'Done !!' }
    format.js { render :js=>'alert("done");' }
  else
    format.html { flash.now[:alert] = "Not done" 
                render "new"
                }
    format.js { render :js=>'alert("not done");' }
  end
end
```

So now,  you just have to get the error messages into the HTML/Javascript sent back,  probably the most railsy way is to just put it into the appropriate .js.erb file.

Comment: +1. I noticed the same problem, but I think a better piece of advice would be to use a browser debugger tool like chrome developer tools. If anything like this happens it comes back with errors immediately. Saved me heaps of time in the past.

Comment: O this works, but my create method shows a form for create the model. Even if I put @course errors_any on the form view, when the creation fails the errors are not show. (Yes I have validated the model w validates presence and bla bla). So Its there a way to do something like  format.js { render :js=>@course.errors.full_messages }. Thx

Answer (score 2):

you have to define the validators in your model.

```
 class Course 
    validates :title, :presence => true
 end
```

In your controller, you have try to save the instance with @course.save .
If it does not save, you get back the errors by calling

```
    @course.errors.full_messages
```

Once you get the hands in these errors , you pass to the view and display a message to the user. don't remember exacly how to do it with format js .

EDIT 2 ========
check this link: http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/
try this

```
    respond_to do |format|
       if @course.save
          format.html { redirect_to admin_index_url, :notice=> 'Done !!' }
          format.js { render :js=>'alert("done");' }
       else
         render :json => @comment.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity
       end
    end  


 In your javascript, bind the error callback and get the errors you passed in your controller.


 $(document).ready(function(){

$('#form_name').bind("ajax:error", function(evt, xhr, status, error){
  var $form = $(this),
      errors,
      errorText;

  try {
    // Populate errorText with the comment errors
    errors = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
  } catch(err) {
    // If the responseText is not valid JSON (like if a 500 exception was thrown), populate errors with a generic error message.
    errors = {message: "Please reload the page and try again"};
  }

  // Build an unordered list from the list of errors
  errorText = "There were errors with the submission: \n<ul>";

  for ( error in errors ) {
    errorText += "<li>" + error + ': ' + errors[error] + "</li> ";
  }

  errorText += "</ul>";

  // Insert error list into form
  $form.find('div.validation-error').html(errorText);
});

});
```

Comment: I have defined the validation on the model, problem is when the creation fails and I'm doing a remote: true, the form dont shows the errors, and I put the logyc for display them

Comment: <% if @course.errors.any? %>
  <div id="errorExplanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@course.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this coursefrom being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
    <% @course.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>

Comment: man, if you're using remote, @course in the view will hold nothing, you don't have access to that variable. You have to pass that errors to your javascript CALLBACK .

Answer (score 2):

I have developed jquery plugin for this purpose. It may worth to take a look at it.

https://github.com/bighostkim/remoteValidation